# Export Photoshop preferences

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Can I somehow export/backup my Adobe Photoshop settings?

All the stuff in Edit -> Preferences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your system, depends on your version of Photoshop.

Say you're on Windows and using Photoshop CS3.

Head yourself to this location:

> C:\Documents and Settings\**[username]**\Application Data\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS3\Adobe Photoshop CS3 Settings

But if you're on a Mac:

> Computer/Users/**[username]**/Library/Preferences/Adobe Photoshop CS3 Settings

Copy all the contents of that folder and that's all your preferences. Next time you re-install, just drop these files back into the same position.

[Tweak as necessary](http://www.photoshopsupport.com/photoshop-blog/08/08/reset-backup-photoshop-preference-file.html) for your setup.